# Add a Tunable delay to a TTL pulse?

Tags: ttl, pll

How can you add a tunable delay to a TTL pulse?

My understanding is that this is the job of a PPL. I am not sure if a digital PLL delays a square wave or if it can also delay a single rising edge (which is desired). I am hoping to tune the delay from 0ms to 10ms with accuracy in the microseconds.

```
________Rising_Edge_At_
Input__: 0,12,84,98,109,130
Output_:   10,22,94,108,119,140
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A phase-locked-loop doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't help.

I'm assuming you need to have the delay accurate on both leading and trailing edges...

Use a micro like a PIC is the easy answer but, if you can't face programming it (this is not a dig at PICs - Olin take note!) then you can use a garage full of D type flip-flops.

It works like this - you input your TTL input to a 74AC74 (you **can** get octal devices but I can't remember the number) and you feed a 1MHz squarewave to the clock. The output from the d type feeds the next d type's input and so on and so forth. About ten thousand d types later you can get the 10millisecond delayed output - it will retain the same shape timewise but aligned to a boundary of the 1usec clock i.e. a 1usec accuracy/resolution.

If you want to reduce the 10ms delay turn the clock up to 10MHz and the delay drops to about 1millisecond. I can't remember what the limit is on 74ACxx devices is, but with a 100MHz it would delay 100usecs. Something in the back of my mind reminds me that 80MHz is the clock limit on AC devices!!

You could use a 100kHz clock then only a thousand d types will be needed  and you'll have a time accuracy/resolution of 10usecs.

I think I'd use a PIC or similar

Comment: I'm a little naive here but how do I input my signal that I need to delay? In see how the counter steps down the 100 Mhz clock to 10mili and creates a square wave. I'm a bit confused on a point. I don't see how my pulse, which can come at intervals of 10ms will be delayed to 10ms+xms (where x is 0,10)?

Comment: Your signal goes into the D input. The positive clock edge passes the input to its output and to the next flip-flop's D input. The 2nd flip-flop passes the 1usec delayed input through on the next +tive clk edge and the output of it is now delayed by 2usec. Keep this going for ten thousand clocks. Of course it's feasible but impractical. If you used a 1kHz clock you'd get 10msec with ten flip-flops but you don't get usec resolution. USe a PIC with interrupts on counters is the best way. BTW - what is a PPL and did you mean PLL = phase locked loop?

Comment: How would you tune a D-FF approach?  A 10Kposition switch?

Comment: @ScottSeidman varying the clock frequency by as much as you can achieves, probably a good deal but yeah a 10k position switch would be ultra cool

Answer (score 1):

Got it!  You need TWO one shots.  A ganged pot would control the width of both of them, which would be the same.  One shot A would have output Qa, and would trigger on a rising edge of the input TTL.  One shot B would have output Qb, and would trigger on the falling edge (notting the input would do it).  The delayed output pulse would then be \$ Q_B\overline{Q_A} \$

This won't work, unfortunately, for delays that are shorter than the width of the original pulse.

For the short delay case, I thing \$ I\overline{Q_A}+Q_B \$ would work, where I is your input pulse, and the Qs are the same as the other case.  I think a latch (or as I would call it, a flip-flop) enabled by \$ I\overline{Q_A}\$  should serve to help switch between the two conditions, and of course, some reset logic would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a '[monostable mulitvibrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator#Monostable_multivibrator_circuit)', 'mono flop', 'one shot', ... If you Google for these terms, you are surely going to find some nice solutions to your problem.

The best solution highly depends on what you are trying to accomplish: voltages, frequency, delay, ... A simple solution *can* be using a 555 timer, but any small microcontroller with an internal oscillator will be up to the job.

Comment: How would you reproduce the width of the original TTL pulse?