# Chip to cause a delay in a pulse

Tags: time, pulse

I was looking to get a delay in a pulse output.
Is there some IC I can use to be able to change the time of the pulse output?

Comment: Depends on the delay. 1 picosecond? 1 nanosecond? 1 second?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a Tunable delay to a TTL pulse?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68265/add-a-tunable-delay-to-a-ttl-pulse)

Comment: People here dont appreciate the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The described function is fulfilled by a *digital delay block IC*: Several manufacturers offer this, with either fixed or programmable delays, with delay applied to both rising and falling edges or only one edge. To narrow down the search, the desired pulse rate or clock frequency needs to be specified, as well as the extent of delay, minimum and maximum.

One versatile option is the Linear Technology [LTC6994-2](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/699412fb.pdf), which delays both rising and falling edges, by a programmable period from 1 microsecond to 33 seconds. If only one edge is to be delayed, the LTC6994-1 is applicable instead.

[image: Pulse delay].

Both ICs permit adjustment of delay period through a separate analog control voltage.

Comment: LT have some good timerblox chips tucked away in their portfolio +1 for revealing that one. Might have to use it myself on a job.

Comment: @Andyaka Good products, but poor retail distribution in India. I've had to order internationally on occasion.